Test (quantify) the association between categorical and numerical variable in survey data
I'm working on the analysis of survey data where the weights are the results of a marginal calibration. The dimension are 968 rows and 168 columns.
My first goal is to compare two subgroups A and B based on some columns of the data. When we gather A and B we have the complete data. I did create categorical variable (named G) in order to know if a row is in A or B. Let's guess we want to compare A and B based on the categorical variable (named F) then I can use rao-Scott test in order to test the association between the variable G and F ?
How can I test the association between the variable G and a numerical variable (named V) ?
Thanks in advance

Testing and quantifying are quite different. You test a nypothesis, you quantify ... well, almost anything, but here, probably some parameter.

I did modify my question

Do you know that you absolutely need to use weights?

In this data, the weights of the individuals are a lot different. Intuitively, considering the weights matters I guess. I'm new in this field

So yes I know that I need to use wieghts.

Well, there are many different ways to use weights, and many types of weights, so it's difficult to know how you should use them in this particular case. However, very generally, to investigate the relationship between one categorical and one continuous variable, if you already have the weights to be used in the data, it's common to regress the continuous on the categorical variable and include the weights into the model.

Okay so if at least one of the coefficients is significative then I can reject the fact that the two variables are independant, isn't it ? How about the validation of the linear model in this case ?

I can say that the weights allow the sample to be a not bad representation of a population. The sum of the weights is greater than the sample size.

You'd really need to 1) describe your dataset, variables, and research questions in more detail, 2) explain what kind of weights do you have and what is the purpose of using them, and 3) edit your model code and output into your question, for us to be able to help more.

What do you mean when you say 2) kind of weights ?

Are they for instance design weights, post-stratification weights, population size weights...? And for what purpose you are using them?

@BencoMyo See https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2020/08/04/weights-in-statistics/ for different uses of the word "weight". As Sointu says, it would be helpful to clarify which kind you're talking about.

I've just had the answer, so the weights are from a marginal calibration.

@Sointu is that more obvious ? thanks
